# How to add <a href> link to make an element clickable in java for Swagger

Tags: java, annotations, swagger

I want to make Capo Mastro a clickable link in Java for swagger in @ApiOperation annotation, but I can't get any result.

```
@ApiOperation(
        value = "This method updates an existing capo mastro."+" <a href>Capo mastro<a>"+ can be managed only by system",
        response = SaveCapoMastroResponse.class
    )
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could help! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you mean clickable in Swagger UI – you can add links in the operation description (`notes` attribute) using the Markdown syntax. The operation summary (`value`) does not support Markdown though.

```
@ApiOperation(
        value = "This method updates an existing capo mastro.",
        notes = "[Capo mastro](http://example.com) can be managed only by system.",
        response = SaveCapoMastroResponse.class
    )
```

HTML `<a href="">` tag should work too, since Markdown supports HTML. Make sure to escape the inner `"` quotes.

```
@ApiOperation(
        value = "This method updates an existing capo mastro.",
        notes = "<a href=\"http://example.com\" target=\"_blank\">Capo mastro</a> can be managed only by system.",
        response = SaveCapoMastroResponse.class
    )
```

Comment: This does not function

Comment: _How exactly_ does this not work? Do you get any errors? Does Swagger UI not render the link? Which version of swagger-annotations are you using? The more details the better.

Comment: It appears the link as a plain text. Swagger 1.5.16

Answer (score 3):

I add clickable image logo to the description:

```
private static ApiInfo v1ApiInfo() {
    return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .version("1.0")
            .title("Council on Dairy Cattle Breeding (CDCB) API v1.0 Documentation"))
            .description("[![cdcb](/img/cdcb.png)](https://www.uscdcb.com/)").build();
}
```

`/img/cdcb.png` - this is image from available resource. I use *SpringBoot + Maven* and it automatically add public folder from resources; full path of image is `/src/main/recources/public/img/cdcb.png`

As result you get clickable image just like you can see below:

[image: cdcb]

Answer (score 1):

You can use **@ExternalDocs** annotation to specify a link for api as below:

```
@ExternalDocs(value="Capo mastro", url="link to Capo mastro")
```

Comment: What did the error you got? which version are you using of Swagger?

Comment: It does not give me any error. It does not show anything at all. I am using swagger  1.5.16

Comment: I am not allowed to change the swagger annotation version as it is a whole project

Comment: IIRC `@ApiOperation` does not support `@ExternalDocs`. Only tags and the "root" Swagger definition support `@ExternalDocs`.